# What is a $(function() { ... }) function and when is it called in the following example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net. I am learning the following code dealing with javascript, my confusion is for $(function(){...} part of code, when it will be called and what is its function? I did not see any code invokes this function.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="tabcontrol/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tabcontrol/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>tab1 info</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>tab2 info</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It comes from the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library you're including:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabcontrol/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

`$` is an alias for the `jQuery` function.

See [jQuery(callback) reference documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#callback):

> A shorthand for `$(document).ready()`.
>
> Allows you to bind a function to be executed when the DOM document has finished loading. This function behaves just like `$(document).ready()`, in that it should be used to wrap other $() operations on your page that depend on the DOM being ready to be operated on. While this function is, technically, chainable - there really isn't much use for chaining against it.

For more information, have a look at [Tutorials:Introducing $(document).ready()](http://tinyurl.com/82gdyx)

Comment: I am wondering what exactly mean document is ready? I am designing page with web parts, and I am not sure what document ready means for web part (e.g. document is loaded before all web parts are loaded)? So, if a webpart in a page needs this javascript function, then I could add this function to head of the page?

Comment: 1. Document ready will happen before webpart loaded or not? 2. Currently all code I showed in my question are in a single aspx page. Now I want to move all remaining html code into a webpart and want to keep the head section the same for the aspx page, not sure whether it works?

Comment: see http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready() for more info

Comment: Any comments or ideas to my question 1 and 2 just above?

Comment: @George2: You should either: Edit your question to include points 1 and 2 in there, or (possibly better as they are different questions) post them as new questions, using the tags [jquery] and [sharepoint]

Answer (score 6):

It will be called when [the document is ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready). It is equivalent to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

Document.ready indicates that the page is fully loaded on the client. WebParts are  serverside controls and will be processed first in order to produce the html document sent to the client. Thus webparts will be processed before the document.ready client-side event fires.

From [the Gecko docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload):

> The load event fires at the end of the document
>   loading process. At this point, all of
>   the objects in the document are in the
>   DOM, and all the images and sub-frames
>   have finished loading.

Comment: What exactly mean document is ready? I am designing page with web parts, and I am not sure what document ready means for web part (e.g. document is loaded before all web parts are loaded)?

Comment: Don't know what 'web parts' is, but `$(document).ready()` basically means the DOM (the access to HTML elements via JavaScript) is ready, but not all images and other external resources are loaded.

Comment: WebPart I mean ASP.Net webpart.

Comment: Ah, I don't have experience with ASP.net whatsoever, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: As @DouweM says, document.ready indicates that the DOM is ready, that is the page is fully loaded on the client. WebParts are a serverside control (apart for some client-side functionality using javascript) and will thus process before the document.ready client-side event fires.

Comment: seriously, what is it with ASP.Net making up ludicrous names for basic HTML... *the output is just HTML!*

Comment: @nickf - to what names are you referring to?

Comment: @Peter "web parts" for starters.

Comment: @nickf - a webpart is not a name for basic HTML, it is specific to a type of server-side control in ASP.Net, basically encapsulating some functionality that can easily be dropped onto a ASP.Net page. The ASP.Net runtime will eventually generate HTML based on the page, but those two things are NOT the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){

});
```

is [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) (a Javascript library) shorthand for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

It is what you use to do with `<body onload="xxx">` but more sophisticated. You can get a fuller explanation [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()).

Comment: I am wondering what exactly mean document is ready? I am designing page with web parts, and I am not sure what document ready means for web part (e.g. document is loaded before all web parts are loaded)?

Comment: 1. Document ready will happen before webpart loaded or not? 2. Currently all code I showed in my question are in a single aspx page. Now I want to move all remaining html code into a webpart and want to keep the head section the same for the aspx page, not sure whether it works?

Comment: Bad jquery, their URL isn't encoded `http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()`

Comment: Any comments or ideas to my question 1 and 2 just above?

Answer (score 2):

That's a shorthand used in jQuery and one that is absolutely unclear and unnecessary in my opinion. Not too long ago, we used to write:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

Now we can also write this to do the above:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

The function that is passed to $(document).ready is executed when the page is loaded and the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) is ready, in other words the document has been loaded in memory. This code is written in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), a Javascript library that makes DOM operations easier.

This is how the above code translates to plain Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
};
```

where `window` is a global object that represents the page [window](http://livingindryden.org/images/home/finishedWindow06052005B.jpg), of course.

Comment: I am wondering what exactly mean document is ready? I am designing page with web parts, and I am not sure what document ready means for web part (e.g. document is loaded before all web parts are loaded)?

Comment: 1. Document ready will happen before webpart loaded or not? 2. Currently all code I showed in my question are in a single aspx page. Now I want to move all remaining html code into a webpart and want to keep the head section the same for the aspx page, not sure whether it works?

Comment: The above code doesn't translate to the plain JS you posted. It adds your function to a queue and calls each sequentially. If it did what you suggest, then subsequent `document.ready` calls would override previous ones.

Comment: Thanks for that update Nick, I didn't know that. Just checked out the jquery docs - "You can have as many $(document).ready events on your page as you like. The functions are then executed in the order they were added."

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you tagged your post "SharePoint" but note that this is not suported on SharePoint pages. 
You need to push scripts that run on page load on a stack and SharePoint will execute them. The syntax is:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myOnloadFunction");
```

This will require the javascript fu:

```
function myOnloadFunction()
{
    $("#tabs").tabs();
}
```

to be available, which can execute your onload code.

Comment: +1 Is there any documentation/API for the SharePoint JS for this, and other methods? I can't seem to find by searching.

Answer (score 1):

This is a jQuery call and it gets called when a document gets loaded.

more info at http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#callback

Comment: I am wondering what exactly mean document is ready? I am designing page with web parts, and I am not sure what document ready means for web part (e.g. document is loaded before all web parts are loaded)?

Comment: You can have multiple $(function(){}) statements. You can even add it to a web part. Browser will trigger all the statements when the browser loads the page. Browser has no idea of a web part. A page is a page for him and the jQuery document ready function is a client side function, therefore it doesn't matter if you have web parts or not. A page is a page for a browser.

Comment: So, if a webpart in a page needs this javascript function, then I could add this function to head of the page?

Comment: 1. Document ready will happen before webpart loaded or not? 2. Currently all code I showed in my question are in a single aspx page. Now I want to move all remaining html code into a webpart and want to keep the head section the same for the aspx page, not sure whether it works?

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is an alias for

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

This event is used in jQuery to invoke a script as soon as the DOM is ready. It's like window.onload, but doesn't wait for all the images to fully load before firing.

Comment: I am wondering what exactly mean document is ready? I am designing page with web parts, and I am not sure what document ready means for web part (e.g. document is loaded before all web parts are loaded)?

Comment: 1. Document ready will happen before webpart loaded or not? 2. Currently all code I showed in my question are in a single aspx page. Now I want to move all remaining html code into a webpart and want to keep the head section the same for the aspx page, not sure whether it works?

Comment: It is separate from ASP, so it doesn't matter how the page is put together server side. Your server outputs all of the HTML at once, correct? As soon as the browser has finished parsing it into a DOM tree, jQuery detects that the code on the 'ready' section can be executed.

Comment: "It is separate from ASP" -- what does "it" mean?

Comment: I mean that your client side code (javascript/jquery) is unconnected to your server side code. Once ASP/.NET/whatever has output the page HTML the browser and javascript take over, and it doesn't matter if you used webparts, etc. to put the page together on the server or not.